# Solr stopwords magic

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solr4, stop-words

My stopwords don't works as expected.
Here is part of my schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_auto">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="3" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="deal_title_terms" type="text_auto" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="deal_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

In stopwords.txt I have next words: the, is, a;
Also I have next data in my fields:

deal_description - This is the my description
deal_title_terms - This is the deal title a terms (will be splitted in terms)

When I try to search deal_description:
Example 1: "deal_description: *his is the m*" - I expect that document with deal_description "This is the my description" will be returned
Example 2: "deal_description: *is th*" - I expect that nothing will be found because "is" and "the" are stopwords.

When I try to search deal_title_terms:
Example 1: "deal_title_terms: *is*" - I expect that nothing will be found because "is" is stopword.
Example 2: "deal_title_terms: *is the deal*" - I expect that "is" and "the" will be ignored and term "deal" will be found.
Example 3: "deal_title_terms: *title a terms*" - I expect that "a" will be ignored and term "title terms" will be found.

Question 1: Why stopwords don't works for "deal_description" field ?
Question 2: Why for field "deal_title_terms" stopwords not removed for my query ?(When I am trying to find *title a terms* it will not find "title terms" term)
Question 3: Is there any way to show stopwords in search result but prevent them from searching ? Example:

data: This is cool search engine
search query : "*is coo*" -> return "This is cool search engine"
search query : "*is*" -> return nothing
search query : "*This coll*" -> return "This is cool search engine"

Question 4: **Where I can find detailed description (maybe with examples) how stopwords works in solr ? Because it looks like magic.**

Comment: To observe what happens with your queries, you can use the solr admin page : http://yourWebsite:8983/solr/#/yourCore/analysis. Put your query and clic on analyse values.

Comment: I am using this tool. With this tool I see that stopwords were removed by query analizer from my query but I still able to find "the", "is" etc. In case when I have stopwords only for my query analizer.

Comment: What is the field that you are using to query?

Comment: I am using "deal_title_terms" with commented stopFilterFactory for analyzer type="index". After restarting solr and reindexing data I am able to find strings like "the".  http://postimg.org/image/ixl40cspp/

Comment: If you are using the edismax query parser then you can make stopwords only searches - this is to solve the "to be or not to be" conumdrum.

Answer (score 5):

Answer to Question 1 : Replace the "KeywordTokenizerFactory" as it does no actual tokenizing, so the entire input string is preserved as a single token.Use StandardTokenizerFactory instead.

Or use the below fieldType.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Stopwords will work as expected for the "deal_description" field.

Answer to Question 3 : Yes. Add the StopFilterFactory in analyzer of type="query" only. It will prevent them from searching and not adding them while indexing.

Answer to Quesion 4 : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Answer to Quesion 2 : The custom field created by you seems incorrect. The text has to tokenised first using the tokenizers but you are using filters first.
Check the analysis of it with solr analysis page.

Comment: I can't use KeywordTokenizerFactory. My search (like this field:*this is my search*) will not work with this filter because looks like it splits string by whitespaces. This page https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters doesn't have stopwords detailed description.